# aws create a machine with mounted volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, volumes

I am using aws ec2 with ubuntu machine 
I would like to create a volume, and every time I create a machine I need it to be attached and mounted to the machine.

Note, this is a single existing volume, and will be mounted to one machine at a time only. I need to start a spot instance and attach and mount that volume every time is an automated way

The way I found so far, I creating the machine using aws-cli, then [attaching the volume using the cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/attach-volume.html), I can't find a way to mount the volume to the machine (I don't want to use ssh to the machine) I thought about using [aws run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), to try and do so, but can't find mount command there. Is there any programatic way to do so, via the cli of some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) script for this. It's an Infrastructure-as-a-code tool which will enable you to create most of the AWS resource in a simple yml file.

For mounting the disks, you can attach it and then mount it to your desired directory via the user data section.

I'll add a sample code below for you.

```
Resources:
  server1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      DisableApiTermination: 'true'
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
      ImageId:
        Ref: AMI
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: WebSG
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: InstanceProfile
      SubnetId:
        Ref: SubnetId
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize:
              Ref: RootVolumeSize
            VolumeType: gp2
        - DeviceName: /dev/sde
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize:
              Ref: AppVolumeSize
            VolumeType: gp2
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |-
          #!/bin/bash -v
          yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
          date > /home/ec2-user/starttime

          #Partition new disks
          echo -e "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw" |fdisk /dev/xvde

          #Make Folders to mount new disks
          mkdir /APP

          #Format disks
          mkfs.ext3 /dev/xvde1

          #Mount New Disks
          mount /dev/xvde1 /APP

          #Add mounts to FSTab so it will stick in reboot
          echo "/dev/xvde1 /APP ext3 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab

          date > /home/ec2-user/stoptime
          echo END
```

To mount an existing volume, define the volume ID in the parameters, for example as 'AppVolume', and mount it to the instance with below code block

```
MountPoint:
  Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
  Properties:
    InstanceId: !Ref 'Ec2Instance'
    VolumeId: !Ref 'AppVolume'
    Device: /dev/sdh
```

You can read more on this in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html)

Comment: Could you detail about the user data section?

Comment: It's set of simple bash commands. First 3 lines is to log data. `#Partition new disks` is to configure the EBS volume mounted. `#Make Folders to mount new disks` to create the mount point directory, `#Format disks` to format the partition created in fdisk and finally the last two to mount and add the entry to the fstab

Comment: could you please post a working example? the issue i see here is that i can not use the user data to mount the volumes because they are not yet attached when I create the machine.

Comment: the whey I see it, this answer is creating a new volume, i need to mount an existing one

Comment: Is this an NFS share? Or a random EBS block?

Comment: just a regular ebs volume, I would like to use it to create data persistence with spot instances

Comment: That makes things even easier. I'll update the answer with the code

Comment: The answer still does not ezplain how to use the ebs as the root volume...